# Proof involving the linear span of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Hi all I'm stuck on a homework question. The question is:

"Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $U = \mathrm{span}\{u_1,...,u_l\}$ and $V = \mathrm{span}\{v_1,...,v_k\}$, for some vectors
$u_1,...,u_l,v_1,...,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $U+V =\mathrm{span}\{u_1,...,u_l,v_1,...,v_k\}$."

I've managed to prove it for the case $k=l$ quite easily but I'm not sure how to do it when $k$ isn't equal to $l$. I thought I could do a double inclusion (show ones in the other and vice versa) but that hasn't got me anywhere.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double inclusion should be enough, consider the following argument:

Let $ a\in U+V$, so there are $v_a\in V$ and $u_a\in U$ such that $a=v_a+u_a$. As $v_a\in V$ and  $u_a\in U$, there exist scalars $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^l$ such that:
$$v_a=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i v_i\quad \text{and}\quad u_a=\sum_{i=1}^l \beta_i u_i$$
Then $a=v_a+u_a\in \text{span}\{v_1,...,v_k,u_1,...,u_l\}$, so $U+V \subseteq \text{span}\{v_1,...,v_k,u_1,...,u_l\}$

Now, I recommend you to think the argument backwards so you can prove the inclusion the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have to show a double inclusion.

First, to show that $U+V$ is contained in $\mathrm{span}\{u_1,...,u_l,v_1,...,v_k\}$ you have to show that any vector of the form $u+v$ belongs there, with $u\in U$ and $v\in V$. Writing
\begin{equation*}
u = \sum_{i=1}^l a_i u_i \quad v = \sum_{j=1}^k b_j v_k
\end{equation*}
with $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{R}$, it is clear that the vector $u+v$ is contained in the subspace spanned by $u_1,...,u_l,v_1,...,v_k$.

Conversely, if $w \in \mathrm{span}\{u_1,...,u_l,v_1,...,v_k\}$ then
\begin{equation*}
w = \sum_{i=1}^l a_i u_i + \sum_{j=1}^k b_j v_j
\end{equation*}
for some $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{R}$, and is thus clear that the first vector lies in $U$ and the second one in $V$. This shows the other inclusion.